# An elegant way to check if any items which has the same childrens exist

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this item:

```
public partial class PACK
{
    public int PACK_IDE { get; set; }
    public string PACK_DESCR { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PACK_DATE_CREATED { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PACK_DATE_MODIFIED { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PACK_DATE_LAST_CALC { get; set; }
    public decimal PACK_COST { get; set; }
    public int PACK_QTY_POSS { get; set; }
    public string PACK_NOTE { get; set; }
    public int PACK_QTY_SOLD { get; set; }
    public decimal PACK_AVRG_SELL_PRICE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PACK_DESTINATION { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<INVENTORY_PACK> INVENTORY_PACK { get; set; }
}
```

Which contains, as you can see, a list of Inventory Packs which are shaped like this:

```
public partial class INVENTORY_PACK
{
    public int INVENT_PACK_IDE { get; set; }
    public int INVENT_IDE { get; set; }
    public int PACK_IDE { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }

    public virtual INVENTORY INVENTORY { get; set; }
    public virtual PACK PACK { get; set; }
}
```

And, lastly, the Inventory Items, which has 2 important fields that are of importance right now:

```
public partial class INVENTORY
{
    public int INVENT_IDE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CARD_IDE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> INVENT_NB_IN_STOCK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> INVENT_NB_QT_SOLD { get; set; }
    public string INVENT_ITEM_STATE { get; set; }

    public virtual CARD CARD { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<INVENTORY_PACK> INVENTORY_PACK { get; set; }
}
```

When I actually save or create a new pack, I need to find a way to check if the actual pack exists that has the exact same Inventory Items based on `INVENT_ITEM_STATE` and `CARD_IDE` and, also, of `QTY` in `INVENTORY_PACK`. If these three values are identical, then we may consider having the same children. I basically need to search through any Packs (using Linq or any Linq-To-Sql call) which childrens are the same as the one I have right now, but I don't really know how to do this except for massive mind-blowing for/foreach loops.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's an example of what I've been trying to do.

```
internal void CreatePack(PackInfo _pack)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            var packQry = from pa in mDb.PACK
                          select pa;

            if (!packQry.Any())
            {
                PACK packToAdd = DataConverter.PackInfoToPACKData(_pack);

                mDb.PACK.Add(packToAdd);

                mDb.SaveChanges();

                int packID = mDb.PACK.Max(_x => _x.PACK_IDE);

                foreach (INVENTORY_PACK inventoryPack in packToAdd.INVENTORY_PACK)
                {
                    inventoryPack.PACK_IDE = packID;

                    mDb.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<PACK> listPacks = new List<PACK>();

                foreach (var inventoryPackInfo in _pack.mListInventoryPackInPack)
                {
                    packQry = from pa in mDb.PACK
                              where pa.INVENTORY_PACK.Any(_item =>
                                      _item.INVENTORY.INVENT_IDE ==
                                      inventoryPackInfo.mInventoryItem.mInventoryID)
                              where pa.INVENTORY_PACK.Any(
                                      _item =>
                                      _item.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE ==
                                      inventoryPackInfo.mInventoryItem.mItemState)
                              where pa.INVENTORY_PACK.Any(_item => _item.QTY == inventoryPackInfo.mQuantity)
                              select pa;

                    if (packQry.Any())
                    {
                        listPacks.AddRange(packQry);
                    }
                }

                if (_pack.mListInventoryPackInPack.Count == 1)
                {

                }

                IDictionary<PACK, int> counts = new Dictionary<PACK, int>();

                foreach (var pack in listPacks)
                {
                    if (!counts.ContainsKey(pack))
                    {
                        counts.Add(pack, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counts[pack]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

I think that I need to clarify my need. Here's an example.

Say that I have 1 `PACK` containing 2 `INVENTORY_PACK`: 1 is an `INVENTORY` item with `INVENT_IDE` 1234, `CARD_IDE` 4321, `QTY` is 1, and `INVENT_ITEM_STATE` is `PERFECT`. The second object is `INVENT_IDE` 4567, `CARD_IDE` 7654, `QTY` is 2 and `INVENT_ITEM_STATE` `PERFECT`.

I need to check through the packages to see if there's already a package containing **exactly** there two items in the selected parameters. So there are many possibilities:

- If we have another existing `PACK` that has the same items and the same number of items (in this case, 2), quantities and IDS, we have a **perfect match** and we consider that the `PACK` already exists;
- If there is a `PACK` containing the same items, but with another one (3 items or more for this example), is it considered **another pack**; then we do not have a match;
- If any package has only one of these items, we do not have a match.

Comment: Can you post some code you tried?

Comment: I will dig in and try to give you back some result, but I'm massively confused as to how to compare 2 objects, so I'm really not sure about comparing 2 list of objects :|

Comment: In my humble opinion, users that mark questions down without providing a reason are not helping.

Comment: Are you trying to work out if every `INVENTORY_PACK` in the collection of the new `PACK` object matches any other? I mean do the three values have to be identical in *every* instance of the `INVENTORY_PACK` collection?

Comment: I am trying to find if ALL the `INVENTORY_PACK` items are exactly found in another PACK. I think that I can come up with an example. I will update my post.

Comment: Updated my post to put an example. See if you have any other questions or if you need more information.

Comment: For clarification, you have the line 'mDb.SaveChanges()'. Are you using the Entity Framework? I ask because some of the answers must be modified if you are using it. Notably, EqualityComparer has issues when used directly on Entity Framework - LINQ calls.

Comment: @AzZa Yes, I am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you could do the following :

Implement two EqualityComparer (may be implemented in your business layer as it's business logic only)

```
class PACK_Comparer : EqualityComparer<PACK>
{
    public override bool Equals(PACK p1, PACK p2)
    {
        // Two PACK are Equals if their INVENTORYs contains the same INVENTORY items
        return (p1.INVENTORY_PACK.Count() == p2.INVENTORY_PACK.Count()
            && p1.INVENTORY_PACK.Intersect(p2.INVENTORY_PACK, new INVENTORY_PACK_Comparer()).Count() == p1.INVENTORY_PACK.Count());
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(PACK p)
    {
        // Ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two PACK p1 and p2
        // then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for p1 must equal the value returned for p2
        INVENTORY_PACK_Comparer comp = new INVENTORY_PACK_Comparer();
        int hCode = 0;
        foreach (var i in p.INVENTORY_PACK)
            hCode ^= comp.GetHashCode(i);
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class INVENTORY_PACK_Comparer : EqualityComparer<INVENTORY_PACK>
{
    public override bool Equals(INVENTORY_PACK i1, INVENTORY_PACK i2)
    {
        // Two INVENTORY_PACK are Equals if their INVENT_ITEM_STATE, CARD_IDE and QTY are Equals
        return (i1.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE == i2.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE
            && i1.INVENTORY.CARD_IDE == i2.INVENTORY.CARD_IDE
            && i1.QTY == i2.QTY);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(INVENTORY_PACK i)
    {
        // Ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two INVENTORY_PACK i1 and i2
        // then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for i1 must equal the value returned for i2
        int hCode = i.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE.GetHashCode()
            ^ i.INVENTORY.CARD_IDE.GetHashCode()
            ^ i.QTY.GetHashCode();
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then check if a same PACK already exist is as short as

```
bool exist = mDb.PACK.Contains(_pack, new PACK_Comparer());
```

And if you want to fetch the actual PACK which already exist in your mDb :

```
PACK_Comparer comp = new PACK_Comparer();
PACK existingPack = mDb.PACK.FirstOrDefault(p => comp.Equals(p, _pack));
```

Note that I removed the 'test is null' things to make it simplier.
You'll need to implement this on your own.

Regards,
Gerard

Comment: Az Za (Comment posted on my post) has a point: I cannot use this method (which seems immensely promising) because I'm using Entity Frameworks. I have the following error when doing so: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[PACK](System.Linq.IQueryable``1[MvcMagicAdmin.Models.DAL.Entities.PACK], MvcMagicAdmin.Models.DAL.Entities.PACK, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer``1[MvcMagicAdmin.Models.DAL.Entities.PACK])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Although the crash is still there, I have worked on a compromise based on your solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Good! I'm glad to see you solved it. I worked through a similar situation; the trick I found was not use 'Contains' but instead to use a local copy of the entity and then use a 'Where.(entity => entity.Contains(_pack, PackComparer))'

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

```
int count = (from p in _pack.INVENTORY_PACK
            where pack.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE == p.INVENTORY.INVENT_ITEM_STATE
            select p).Count();
```

After that check for    `if(pack.QTY == count)`

Comment: Well, that will allows me to check any pack that has the same number of items, you have a point. But how can I compare each items separately to make sure that the items in the pack are the same as the one I'm trying so save / create?

Comment: And it any of my items does not share the same `INVENT_ITEM_STATE`, will this allows me to check out too? I'm not sure

Comment: you will have to handle them by writing a bunch of if & else loops

Comment: I've updated my code above as I've been trying things out, you may look around

Comment: try to debug each step if the values are getting populated.. since your objects are a little complex & intricate it would be tough to write working code without debugging.